# Blue highlight of elements Cordova / Phonegap app too big when using Jquery .on()

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Android highlights HTML-elements when clicking them, which I like because it makes a web app seem more responsive. However, when using Jquery `.on()` to add a `.click()` event to all future children of a parent element, the parent is highlighted on click instead of the child. Is there an easy workaround for this?

I don't consider running a function that adds a `.click()` event to a new child each time one is created a good option, but perhaps it's the only one. Note that this app is wrapped up using Cordova / Phonegap, I don't know if it behaves the same way in a browser on Android.

The behaviour in action (when clicking):

```
$("#calendar").on("click", ".date", function() {
    //do_something();
});
```

[image: parent is incorrectly highlighted]

```
$(".date").click(function() {
    //do_something();
});
```

[image: correct behaviour, but no updating .click() event :(]

Comment: You can remove that effects by using css property

Comment: @JDev If you're referring to setting -webkit-tap-highlight-color to rgba(0,0,0,0) in order to remove the selection; I'm aware of that, but I wish to keep the selection intact in order to make the app feel more responsive.

Comment: Ahh.. that is fine i mean to say you can disable effects using -webkit-tap-highlight-color to rgba(0,0,0,0) and can try .active css property to display touch effect on any element.